# IIS - 2 Issues in one > SSL Binding Cert selected but will not stick | Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate

Using WACS, I created individual certs for each domain.
(I have been using WACS for years, but only creating one bundled Cert with all Domains in one Cert. Which has worked, but now I am creating each domain with its own Cert.)

> Windows 2016 Server Core
> IIS 10

Following Steps.
IIS > Sites > DomainName

Step 1: [Bindings]
Step 2: Select [https | Domain.com]
Step 2a: ERROR MESSAGE

> ---
>
> ### Edit Site Binding
>
> ### There was an error while performing this operation.
> Details:
> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

I have to click 4 times to get out of the warning dialog. (Very annoying)

Step 3: click the [Select] button.
Step 4: Choose the SSL for that domain. (domain.com)
Step 4a: Make sure [Require Server Name Indication] is Unchecked.
Step 5: Click [OK]
Step 6: Choose [Yes] to the dialog stating that another site is using the binding.
(I'm not sure why it is asking this when each Cert is for each domain, one for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), one for Sub1.example.com, and one for sub2.example.com, etc.)
Step 7: Click [Close]
Step 8: Load the page in the browser to make sure it is working; CHECK.

Now, this is when it gets stupid.
I have other domains I have to assign their new Certs to.
Once I choose another domain and perform the above operation,
it will reset ALL OTHER websites' SSL to the one I chose.
If I go back and change them all back, they will all change again.

While typing this up, I checked to see if I could assign the certs starting from the bottommost domain in the tree to see if maybe that would work, and it does not. It also changes all domains to the last selected Cert.

I have done the certs two different ways to see if one would work over the other.
WACS | Manual | 2 (Manual Input of domains) |
In this step, choosing which Cert to create, I choose each on two different runs.
1: Separate certificate for each domain (e.g., *.example.com)
2: Separate certificate for each host (e.g., sub.example.com)

Both run without issue, and I set them in IIS, and once I change another of the others, the same issue as above happens.

As it sits right now, all my sites are down with the dreaded

> > Your connection is not private

So, two questions.
#1: Why is this happening?
#2: Why do I get the error  (Index was outside the bounds of the array.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems a little more checking, and I would have found the answer.
[Binding SSL certificate to a new site, changes other's certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266411/binding-ssl-certificate-to-a-new-site-changes-others-certificate)

So, what I need to do is put enough local IP Addresses into the server, and then I will be able to run individual certs so until that time, I will have to do them all as ONE cert. Which works, and the sites are back up and running, and that is what I needed.

So, unless someone has something else to add to this, I guess it is closed.

Comment: "So, what I need to do is put enough local IP Addresses into the server, and then I will be able to run individual certs so until that time, I will have to do them all as ONE cert. Which works, and the sites are back up and running, and that is what I needed" sounds like a red flag. IIS 8 and above started to support SNI, like the linked thread indicated. You should embrace that to host multiple HTTPS sites on a single IP. If the tool WACS does not give you the capability, you should dump it and find something else.

Comment: Hey, Lex. The only reason why I never used SNI is that I kept getting the warning "No default SSL site has been created." I went with what you said and made all sites use SNI, and two of my sites that were having loop issues suddenly began working like they should. So all is good.
If you would like to post what you wrote here as an Answer, I will accept that.
Also. Do you have any ideas on the warning dialog about "being out of range," what it means, and how to stop it from appearing? Thanks.

Comment: "There was an error while performing this operation. Details: Index was outside the bounds of the array" is a typical exception message that indicates something wrong with the tool (IIS Manager in your case?) But since all sites are using SNI and working right now, you can neglect it.